# Manual TLS handshake without TCP

Tags: tls, openssl

TLS requires reliable transport but is not bound to TCP. How can I perform a TLS 1.3 handshake through a non-TCP channel with OpenSSL - for example by exchanging a number of files between participating communication partners?

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect that OpenSSL in particular supports anything other than TLS/TCP and DTLS/UDP?

Comment: This is a pure programming question. In OpenSSL [BIO](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/BIO) provides an abstraction of the underlying transport and thus can be used to implement TLS on top of whatever transport you want.

Comment: @CBHAcking: OpenSSL works on top of OpenVN as well. TLS is used as well in some EAP-metdhods and for QUIC initialization.

Comment: I meant that OpenSSL gives you the tool to use TLS on top of custom transports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL has its own framework for I/O abstraction (BIO).

For example, OpenVPN uses TLS on top of the OpenVPN protocol. The [`key_state_ssl_init()`](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/b66701e5e2ef194f33e2a8865a4abf4567466d83/src/openvpn/ssl_openssl.c#L1874) function of OpenVPN is used to setup the NIO layers. It setups the SSL BIO to communicate with [in-memory/buffer BIO](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/BIO_s_mem.html):

```
void
key_state_ssl_init(struct key_state_ssl *ks_ssl, const struct tls_root_ctx *ssl_ctx, bool is_server, struct tls_session *session)
{
  // ...

  ASSERT((ks_ssl->ssl_bio = BIO_new(BIO_f_ssl())));
  ASSERT((ks_ssl->ct_in = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())));
  ASSERT((ks_ssl->ct_out = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())));

  // ...

  if (is_server)
  {
    SSL_set_accept_state(ks_ssl->ssl);
  }
  else
  {
    SSL_set_connect_state(ks_ssl->ssl);
  }

  SSL_set_bio(ks_ssl->ssl, ks_ssl->ct_in, ks_ssl->ct_out);
  BIO_set_ssl(ks_ssl->ssl_bio, ks_ssl->ssl, BIO_NOCLOSE);
}
```